# Best practice to add new object to javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need the best practices for advice. 
Let's Assume I have a trucks object like this:

```
    var trucks = [
    {truckId:"1", Manufacturer:"Toyota", Type:"Tacoma", NoSeries:"1",mileage:"5000" },
    {truckId:"2", Manufacturer:"Ford", Type:"F-150", NoSeries:"2",mileage:"7644"},
    {truckId:"5", Manufacturer:"Geely", Type:"Bear", NoSeries:"5", mileage:"156778"},
    {truckId:"3", Manufacturer:"Nissan", Type:"Pathfinder", NoSeries:"3", mileage:"6722"},
    {truckId:"4", Manufacturer:"Tesla", Type:"Cybertruck", NoSeries:"4", mileage:"999999"},
 ];
```

and I want to add this new maintenance record object:

```
 let newmaintenanceRecord = 
[
    {complains: "Broken AC", action: "Fixed Leaky Condensor"}, 
    {complains: "sounds like a hammer pounding midget in the trunk", action: "took hammer away from midget"}, 
]
```

into the truckId#5 object.

I tried these lines on the project but it says the trucks are not iterable,

```
    let index = trucks.findIndex(truck => truck.truckId==="5");
    trucks = [...trucks[index], newmaintenanceRecord];
    console.log(trucks);
```

These lines erased all trucks object except the new record

```
trucks = [trucks[index],...newmaintenanceRecord];
```

Comment: `trucks[index].maintenance = newmaintenanceRecord`…?! What's the result supposed to look like exactly?

Comment: Do you really need an array? It is much easier to work with an object and refer to its items through their keys directly. Otherwise, as mentioned in the answer, you will need some kind of mapping, or iterate each time through the array items, which is not optimal.

Comment: Maybe next time try and find a [less offensive](https://twitter.com/warwickadavis/status/931312514234830848?lang=en) example to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you found the index of the truck with: `let index = trucks.findIndex(truck => truck.truckId==="5");`, you can modify this certain object: `trucks[index].maintenence = newmaintenanceRecord`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
[ ...trucks[index],
```

But `trucks[index]` is an object, not an array, so the object can't be spread into an array.

If you want to change the object at that index to add the new property, use `.find` to get a reference to the object, then assign a new property to it, containing the `newmaintenanceRecord`:

```
const truck = trucks.find(truck => truck.truckId==="5"));
if (truck) {
  truck.newmaintenanceRecord = newmaintenanceRecord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't overcomplicate your code and simply add a property to the object

```js
const trucks = [
{truckId:"1", Manufacturer:"Toyota", Type:"Tacoma", NoSeries:"1",mileage:"5000" },
{truckId:"2", Manufacturer:"Ford", Type:"F-150", NoSeries:"2",mileage:"7644"},
{truckId:"5", Manufacturer:"Geely", Type:"Bear", NoSeries:"5", mileage:"156778"},
{truckId:"3", Manufacturer:"Nissan", Type:"Pathfinder", NoSeries:"3", mileage:"6722"},
{truckId:"4", Manufacturer:"Tesla", Type:"Cybertruck", NoSeries:"4", mileage:"999999"},
];

const newmaintenanceRecord = 
[
    {complains: "Broken AC", action: "Fixed Leaky Condensor"}, 
    {complains: "sounds like a hammer pounding midget in the trunk", action: "took hammer away from midget"}, 
]


function addMaintainance(trucks, truckId, maintainanceRecords) {
  const truck5 = trucks.find(({truckId: id}) => id === truckId);
  if (truck5) {
    truck5.maintainance = (truck5.maintainance || []).concat(...maintainanceRecords);
  }
  return trucks;
}

console.log(addMaintainance(trucks, "5", newmaintenanceRecord));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
trucks.forEach((truck)=>{
if(truck.truckId === '5'){
    truck.maintenanceRecord = newmaintenanceRecord;
   }
}
```